# Converting CSV (JSON) data into separate sheets in excel using ID's and timestamps

Tags: python, json, excel, csv

I have several soil moisture sensors logging moisture and temperature data at different depths in field. I am trying to reformat data from a CSV file (the data is recorded as a json msg) into a new CSV file.

I have included the code I have used to separate data into different columns and remove the transceiver data but I am wanting to create a new sheet for each 'sensor ID' and have these organized by the timestamp (in date  & time format).

My current code is:

```
import csv

source_filename = r"C:\*source file path*\mycsv1.csv"
target_filename = r"C:\*output file path*\mycsv2.csv"

temp1 = []
def removeSegment(temp8,temp7):
    temp11 = ""
    temp9 = temp8.split(",")
    for temp10 in range(len(temp9)):
        if (temp7 not in temp9[temp10]):
            if (len(temp11)==0):
                temp11 = temp9[temp10]
            else:
                temp11 = temp11 + "," + temp9[temp10]
    return temp11
with open(source_filename) as myfile:
    myreader = csv.reader(myfile)
    for myrow in myreader:
        if ("sensor" in myrow[1]) and ("val" not in myrow[2]):
            temp1.append("sensor_id:"+myrow[1].split("/")[1]+","+myrow[2].replace('"','')[1:-1])
temp3 = dict()
for temp2 in range(len(temp1)):
    temp4 = temp1[temp2].split(",")
    for temp5 in range(len(temp4)):
        temp6 = temp4[temp5]
        if (temp6.split(":")[0] == "timestamp"):
            temp3[temp6.split(":")[1]] = removeSegment(temp1[temp2],"timestamp")
mywriter = open(target_filename, 'w')
mywriter.write('timestamp,sensor_id,m1,m2,t1,t2,t3,t4\n')
for temp12, temp13 in temp3.items():
    mywriter.write(temp12+",")
    temp15 = temp13.split(",")
    for temp14 in range(len(temp15)):
        mywriter.write(temp15[temp14].split(":")[1])
        if temp14 == len(temp15)-1:
            mywriter.write("\n")
        else:
            mywriter.write(",")
mywriter.close()
```

I had a colleague from work help me write the code to extract the timestamp but there is an error in the conversion and only 10 digits are transferred to the new sheet instead of 13.

Additionally, I am struggling to group the data for each 'sensor ID' (each different sensor) on a new 'sheet/page' on excel. For example under the topic column, sensor/200301000000000000000000 = sensor 301. This would require all data from this sensor under a new sheet ordered by date & time.

Sample of CSV dataset in text format:

```
> receivedTS    topic   messageData
1.62967E+12 sensor/200301000000000000000000/501 {"m1":210,"m2":359,"t1":83,"t2":87,"t3":91,"t4":96,"timestamp":1629668261}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200300000000000000000000/501 {"m1":285,"m2":384,"t1":82,"t2":85,"t3":86,"t4":88,"timestamp":1629667612}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200294000000000000000000/501 {"m1":310,"m2":406,"t1":67,"t2":73,"t3":83,"t4":83,"timestamp":1629667609}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200297000000000000000000/501 {"m1":198,"m2":371,"t1":80,"t2":85,"t3":86,"t4":92,"timestamp":1629667604}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200303000000000000000000/501 {"m1":495,"m2":483,"t1":85,"t2":90,"t3":95,"t4":97,"timestamp":1629667600}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200302000000000000000000/501 {"m1":499,"m2":463,"t1":102,"t2":107,"t3":106,"t4":108,"timestamp":1629667596}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200296000000000000000000/501 {"m1":258,"m2":358,"t1":88,"t2":93,"t3":96,"t4":95,"timestamp":1629667592}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200298000000000000000000/501 {"m1":381,"m2":358,"t1":77,"t2":83,"t3":86,"t4":86,"timestamp":1629667584}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200187000000000000000000/501 {"m1":248,"m2":386,"t1":78,"t2":85,"t3":91,"t4":87,"timestamp":1629667580}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200295000000000000000000/501 {"m1":219,"m2":416,"t1":85,"t2":90,"t3":88,"t4":92,"timestamp":1629667576}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200301000000000000000000/501 {"m1":210,"m2":359,"t1":83,"t2":87,"t3":91,"t4":96,"timestamp":1629667573}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200300000000000000000000/501 {"m1":285,"m2":384,"t1":82,"t2":86,"t3":87,"t4":88,"timestamp":1629666929}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200294000000000000000000/501 {"m1":311,"m2":407,"t1":67,"t2":73,"t3":83,"t4":83,"timestamp":1629666925}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200297000000000000000000/501 {"m1":198,"m2":371,"t1":80,"t2":85,"t3":86,"t4":92,"timestamp":1629666920}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200303000000000000000000/501 {"m1":495,"m2":483,"t1":83,"t2":90,"t3":96,"t4":97,"timestamp":1629666916}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200302000000000000000000/501 {"m1":499,"m2":463,"t1":102,"t2":107,"t3":107,"t4":108,"timestamp":1629666912}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200296000000000000000000/501 {"m1":258,"m2":358,"t1":90,"t2":93,"t3":96,"t4":96,"timestamp":1629666908}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200299000000000000000000/501 {"m1":248,"m2":354,"t1":77,"t2":85,"t3":88,"t4":92,"timestamp":1629666904}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200298000000000000000000/501 {"m1":381,"m2":359,"t1":77,"t2":83,"t3":85,"t4":86,"timestamp":1629666900}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200187000000000000000000/501 {"m1":248,"m2":386,"t1":78,"t2":85,"t3":91,"t4":87,"timestamp":1629666895}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200295000000000000000000/501 {"m1":219,"m2":416,"t1":85,"t2":90,"t3":88,"t4":92,"timestamp":1629666891}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200301000000000000000000/501 {"m1":210,"m2":359,"t1":83,"t2":87,"t3":91,"t4":96,"timestamp":1629666889}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200300000000000000000000/501 {"m1":285,"m2":384,"t1":82,"t2":85,"t3":87,"t4":90,"timestamp":1629666244}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200294000000000000000000/501 {"m1":310,"m2":406,"t1":67,"t2":73,"t3":83,"t4":83,"timestamp":1629666240}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200297000000000000000000/501 {"m1":198,"m2":371,"t1":80,"t2":85,"t3":86,"t4":91,"timestamp":1629666236}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200303000000000000000000/501 {"m1":495,"m2":483,"t1":83,"t2":90,"t3":96,"t4":97,"timestamp":1629666233}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200302000000000000000000/501 {"m1":499,"m2":463,"t1":102,"t2":107,"t3":107,"t4":108,"timestamp":1629666228}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200296000000000000000000/501 {"m1":259,"m2":358,"t1":90,"t2":93,"t3":96,"t4":96,"timestamp":1629666224}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200299000000000000000000/501 {"m1":248,"m2":354,"t1":77,"t2":85,"t3":87,"t4":92,"timestamp":1629666219}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200298000000000000000000/501 {"m1":381,"m2":358,"t1":77,"t2":83,"t3":85,"t4":86,"timestamp":1629666215}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200187000000000000000000/501 {"m1":249,"m2":386,"t1":78,"t2":85,"t3":91,"t4":87,"timestamp":1629666210}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200295000000000000000000/501 {"m1":219,"m2":416,"t1":85,"t2":90,"t3":88,"t4":91,"timestamp":1629666207}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200301000000000000000000/501 {"m1":208,"m2":359,"t1":83,"t2":87,"t3":91,"t4":95,"timestamp":1629666204}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200300000000000000000000/501 {"m1":285,"m2":384,"t1":82,"t2":86,"t3":86,"t4":88,"timestamp":1629665560}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200294000000000000000000/501 {"m1":310,"m2":406,"t1":67,"t2":75,"t3":83,"t4":83,"timestamp":1629665553}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200297000000000000000000/501 {"m1":198,"m2":371,"t1":80,"t2":85,"t3":86,"t4":92,"timestamp":1629665549}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200303000000000000000000/501 {"m1":495,"m2":483,"t1":85,"t2":90,"t3":96,"t4":97,"timestamp":1629665546}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200302000000000000000000/501 {"m1":499,"m2":463,"t1":103,"t2":107,"t3":107,"t4":108,"timestamp":1629665542}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200296000000000000000000/501 {"m1":259,"m2":358,"t1":90,"t2":93,"t3":96,"t4":96,"timestamp":1629665536}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200299000000000000000000/501 {"m1":248,"m2":354,"t1":77,"t2":85,"t3":87,"t4":92,"timestamp":1629665532}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200298000000000000000000/501 {"m1":381,"m2":359,"t1":78,"t2":83,"t3":86,"t4":86,"timestamp":1629665527}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200187000000000000000000/501 {"m1":249,"m2":386,"t1":78,"t2":85,"t3":91,"t4":87,"timestamp":1629665524}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200295000000000000000000/501 {"m1":220,"m2":416,"t1":85,"t2":90,"t3":88,"t4":92,"timestamp":1629665519}
1.62967E+12 sensor/200301000000000000000000/501 {"m1":208,"m2":359,"t1":83,"t2":87,"t3":91,"t4":95,"timestamp":1629665516}
1.62967E+12 transceiver/004900314E46500D2033334D/data/mains-voltage {"mv":21379,"timestamp":1629664992}
1.62967E+12 transceiver/004900314E46500D2033334D/data/battery-voltage   {"mv":13638,"timestamp":1629664992}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200300000000000000000000/501 {"m1":285,"m2":384,"t1":82,"t2":85,"t3":87,"t4":88,"timestamp":1629664872}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200294000000000000000000/501 {"m1":310,"m2":406,"t1":67,"t2":75,"t3":83,"t4":83,"timestamp":1629664869}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200297000000000000000000/501 {"m1":198,"m2":371,"t1":80,"t2":85,"t3":86,"t4":91,"timestamp":1629664864}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200303000000000000000000/501 {"m1":495,"m2":483,"t1":85,"t2":90,"t3":96,"t4":97,"timestamp":1629664860}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200302000000000000000000/501 {"m1":499,"m2":463,"t1":103,"t2":107,"t3":107,"t4":108,"timestamp":1629664857}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200296000000000000000000/501 {"m1":259,"m2":358,"t1":90,"t2":93,"t3":96,"t4":96,"timestamp":1629664853}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200299000000000000000000/501 {"m1":248,"m2":354,"t1":77,"t2":85,"t3":87,"t4":92,"timestamp":1629664846}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200298000000000000000000/501 {"m1":381,"m2":359,"t1":78,"t2":85,"t3":85,"t4":86,"timestamp":1629664842}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200187000000000000000000/501 {"m1":249,"m2":386,"t1":78,"t2":85,"t3":91,"t4":87,"timestamp":1629664838}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200295000000000000000000/501 {"m1":220,"m2":416,"t1":85,"t2":90,"t3":90,"t4":92,"timestamp":1629664834}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200301000000000000000000/501 {"m1":211,"m2":359,"t1":85,"t2":87,"t3":91,"t4":95,"timestamp":1629664831}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200300000000000000000000/501 {"m1":285,"m2":384,"t1":82,"t2":86,"t3":87,"t4":88,"timestamp":1629664187}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200294000000000000000000/501 {"m1":310,"m2":406,"t1":67,"t2":73,"t3":83,"t4":83,"timestamp":1629664180}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200297000000000000000000/501 {"m1":198,"m2":371,"t1":80,"t2":85,"t3":86,"t4":92,"timestamp":1629664177}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200303000000000000000000/501 {"m1":495,"m2":483,"t1":85,"t2":90,"t3":96,"t4":97,"timestamp":1629664172}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200302000000000000000000/501 {"m1":499,"m2":463,"t1":105,"t2":107,"t3":107,"t4":108,"timestamp":1629664168}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200296000000000000000000/501 {"m1":259,"m2":358,"t1":90,"t2":93,"t3":96,"t4":95,"timestamp":1629664164}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200299000000000000000000/501 {"m1":249,"m2":354,"t1":77,"t2":85,"t3":87,"t4":91,"timestamp":1629664160}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200298000000000000000000/501 {"m1":381,"m2":359,"t1":77,"t2":85,"t3":85,"t4":86,"timestamp":1629664154}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200187000000000000000000/501 {"m1":249,"m2":386,"t1":78,"t2":85,"t3":91,"t4":87,"timestamp":1629664150}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200295000000000000000000/501 {"m1":219,"m2":416,"t1":85,"t2":90,"t3":88,"t4":92,"timestamp":1629664147}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200301000000000000000000/501 {"m1":210,"m2":359,"t1":83,"t2":87,"t3":91,"t4":96,"timestamp":1629664143}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200300000000000000000000/501 {"m1":285,"m2":384,"t1":82,"t2":86,"t3":87,"t4":90,"timestamp":1629663497}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200294000000000000000000/501 {"m1":310,"m2":406,"t1":67,"t2":75,"t3":83,"t4":83,"timestamp":1629663493}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200297000000000000000000/501 {"m1":198,"m2":371,"t1":80,"t2":85,"t3":86,"t4":92,"timestamp":1629663489}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200303000000000000000000/501 {"m1":495,"m2":483,"t1":85,"t2":90,"t3":96,"t4":97,"timestamp":1629663487}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200302000000000000000000/501 {"m1":499,"m2":463,"t1":103,"t2":107,"t3":107,"t4":108,"timestamp":1629663478}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200296000000000000000000/501 {"m1":259,"m2":358,"t1":90,"t2":93,"t3":96,"t4":95,"timestamp":1629663474}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200299000000000000000000/501 {"m1":248,"m2":354,"t1":77,"t2":85,"t3":87,"t4":92,"timestamp":1629663468}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200298000000000000000000/501 {"m1":381,"m2":359,"t1":78,"t2":83,"t3":85,"t4":86,"timestamp":1629663464}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200187000000000000000000/501 {"m1":249,"m2":386,"t1":78,"t2":85,"t3":91,"t4":87,"timestamp":1629663460}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200295000000000000000000/501 {"m1":219,"m2":416,"t1":86,"t2":90,"t3":88,"t4":92,"timestamp":1629663456}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200301000000000000000000/501 {"m1":210,"m2":359,"t1":85,"t2":87,"t3":92,"t4":95,"timestamp":1629663453}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200300000000000000000000/501 {"m1":285,"m2":384,"t1":83,"t2":86,"t3":87,"t4":88,"timestamp":1629662809}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200294000000000000000000/501 {"m1":310,"m2":406,"t1":67,"t2":75,"t3":83,"t4":83,"timestamp":1629662806}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200297000000000000000000/501 {"m1":198,"m2":371,"t1":80,"t2":85,"t3":86,"t4":91,"timestamp":1629662801}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200303000000000000000000/501 {"m1":495,"m2":483,"t1":85,"t2":90,"t3":96,"t4":97,"timestamp":1629662798}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200302000000000000000000/501 {"m1":499,"m2":463,"t1":105,"t2":107,"t3":107,"t4":108,"timestamp":1629662789}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200296000000000000000000/501 {"m1":259,"m2":358,"t1":90,"t2":93,"t3":96,"t4":96,"timestamp":1629662786}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200299000000000000000000/501 {"m1":249,"m2":354,"t1":77,"t2":85,"t3":87,"t4":91,"timestamp":1629662779}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200298000000000000000000/501 {"m1":380,"m2":359,"t1":78,"t2":83,"t3":85,"t4":86,"timestamp":1629662776}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200187000000000000000000/501 {"m1":249,"m2":386,"t1":78,"t2":85,"t3":91,"t4":87,"timestamp":1629662772}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200295000000000000000000/501 {"m1":219,"m2":416,"t1":85,"t2":90,"t3":88,"t4":92,"timestamp":1629662768}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200301000000000000000000/501 {"m1":210,"m2":359,"t1":85,"t2":88,"t3":91,"t4":95,"timestamp":1629662764}
1.62966E+12 sensor/200300000000000000000000/501 {"m1":285,"m2":384,"t1":82,"t2":86,"t3":87,"t4":88,"timestamp":1629662120}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use pandas for this:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('<your filepath goes here>', dtype=str)

df.receivedTS = df.receivedTS.apply(lambda x: int(float(x)))


def extract_sensor_id(row):
    if 'sensor' in row:
        identifying_number = row.split('/')[1]
        # I'm assuming that sensor ids are only three digit numbers that come after 200
        # This won't work otherwise but is very resolvable if you know the naming convention
        # At present the code just gets 4th, 5th, 6th digits of the number
        sensor_id = identifying_number[3:6]
        return sensor_id

df['sensor_id'] = df.topic.apply(extract_sensor_id)

# To print out values for sensor id 301
print(df.loc[df.sensor_id == '301'].sort_values(by='receivedTS'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can see how this separates the data into separate datasets for each sensor in the terminal. Following this how can I write this data to an excel sheet and  create a new sheet for each sensor data?